# MPI - Send/Recv Array of Doubles. Output is Whacky

Tags: c++, c, process, multiprocessing, mpi

I am trying to send an array of double values, or if that's not possible then just one value at a time, from each process I have, back to the master to tally up all the numbers. When I tried sending one value, the number comes out as some crazy huge negative number. When I tried sending an int the same thing happened. Some of my code is below:

```
//this is the send
MPI_Isend(&handArray[ROYALFLUSH], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, ROYALFLUSH, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

//This is the master receiving the msg
MPI_Irecv(dubBuff, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i+1, h, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
```

When I proceed to cout the values in dubBuff with a loop it spits out whacky numbers.

P.S. dubBuff is just an array like so:

```
double dubBuff[10];
```

How do I properly send my array values back up to the master process?

Comment: Not specific to your question, but if you're new to MPI don't use the nonblocking calls.  Stick with `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` until you have a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: I agree with @eduffy here - are you doing an `MPI_Wait()` between the Irecv and the cout?